# val или fun в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda

Недавно начал писать на языке Kotlin и у меня возникло много вопросов о **fun** and **val**, например, чем отличаются эти два случая:

1. ```
   val handleMessage (Message) -> Unit = { message -> 
       /* do something here */ 
   }
   ```
2. ```
   fun handleMessage(message : Message){
       /* do something here*/
   }
   ```

Я хотел бы узнать есть ли между ними какая-нибудь серьезная разница и почему я должен в похожих случаях пользоваться одним, а не другим.

P.S. Я знаю что **val** immutable и обычно его используют для того, чтобы хранить данные

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: [Kotlin Programmer Dictionary: Function Type vs Function literal vs Lambda expression vs Anonymous function](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-function-type-vs-function-literal-vs-lambda-expression-vs-anonymous-edc97e8873e)

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за замечание, что же касается ссылки - первая при вводе такого вопроса в гугл, сам доклад был для меня очень полезен, но в данном докладе не приводится сравнение двух данных случаев, там приводятся примеры использования анонимных функций и рефлексии, к сожалению, это не совсем то

Comment: [Function definition: fun vs val](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36119407/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy , спасибо за то, что скидывали ссылки на полезные ресурсы, проанализировав их и прочтя дополнительную литературу я понял, в чем заключается различие.

Comment: Не забудь написать ответ на свой вопрос:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Большое спасибо @Grundy за помощь в поисках ответа.

```
val handleMessage : (Message) -> Unit{  
     message -> /* do something */  
}
```

данный код создает новый класс:

```
class A : (Message) -> Unit {
    override fun invoke(message : Message) {
        /* do something*/
    }
}
```

Т.е. при обращении к лямбда выражению у нас создается новый класс и вызывается метод *invoke* с заданным параметром.
В случае **fun**:

```
fun handleMessage(message: Message){
    /* do something*/
}
```

данный код компилируется в следующий java-код:

```
public class ExampleClass{
    void handleMessage(Message message){
        /* do something */
    }
}
```

**Итог:**
1. **fun** - обыкновенная функция, которая превращается в обычный метод, в то время как **val** создает новый класс и вызывает его метод *invoke* с переданными параметрами.
2. Если вы пишите на Android, стоит избегать использования **val** лямбда выражений

Comment: Итог очень спорный. №1 зависит от scope, т.е. где вы fun создаете. №2 это самый обычный анонимный класс, с чего вдруг сразу избегать? Использовать разумно и понимая что пишешь, это да.

Comment: в первом случае будет не класс, интефейс, я в байткоде видел